# What are some examples of psychology studies with tiny effect sizes and tiny p-values that are good for teaching?

Tags: statistics, teaching-of-psychology

I'm looking for examples of studies where the result is highly significant but the effect is so tiny that it is meaningless in a practical sense. These will be shared with undergraduate psychology students to illustrate that statistically significant doesn't always mean important or consequential.

Comment: There's the recent [Facebook emotion contagion study](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/24/8788.full.pd) (e.g., "P < 0.001, Cohen’s d = 0.02" and "P = 0.007, d = 0.001").

Comment: Problem might get worse if you include CIs - as many CIs reported in studies with low p values include very low effect sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example might be the effect of birth order on intelligence. Given a large enough sample there highly significant effects (p<.00001). However, these effects are very very small.

For a recent example, see Rohrer, Egloff, and Schmukle (2015): the effect of one birth order position was only one tenth of a standard deviation (1.5 IQ points)

> To illustrate this small effect, in our between-family sample of sibships of two, a randomly picked firstborn had a 52% chance of having a higher IQ than a randomly picked secondborn; conversely, a secondborn had a 48% chance of having a higher IQ than a firstborn.

**References**

Rohrer, J. M., Egloff, B., & Schmukle, S. C. (2015). Examining the effects of birth order on personality. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 201506451. http://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1506451112